# Permutating Result Set of My Query, Something is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables:

1. Persons
2. Jobs
3. Titles
4. Departments

Persons Table

```
id | title_id | person | phone | email | dept_id | job_id
---+----------+--------+-------+-------+---------+-------
1  |        1 | some1  | 12345 | s@a.c |       2 |      3
...
```

Other tables' structures are same as the following

```
id | ******** 
---+---------
```

Assume that there are 5 records in table titles, 5 records in table departments and 5 job records in table jobs.

And let's say suitable records defined by $search string = 6 in table persons;

When I execute the query below, the result set has  `5 x 5 x 5 x 6 = 750` records and most of them are repetitive. The results look like doing permutation.

```
$query = sprintf(
                  "SELECT * 
                   FROM 
                         persons p, titles t, departments d, jobs j 
                   WHERE 
                         p.person LIKE %s OR 
                         p.phone LIKE %s OR 
                         p.email LIKE %s AND 
                         p.id=t.id AND 
                         p.id=j.id AND 
                         p.id=d.id", 
                   $search, $search, $search
                  );
```

Then I have tried to changed the conditions as the following:

```
$query = sprintf(
                  "SELECT * 
                   FROM 
                         persons p, titles t, departments d, jobs j 
                   WHERE 
                         p.person LIKE %s OR 
                         p.phone LIKE %s OR 
                         p.email LIKE %s AND 
                         p.title_id=t.id AND 
                         p.job_id=j.id AND 
                         p.dept_id=d.id", 
                   $search, $search, $search
                  );
```

This returns the same result.
I just want to get title's itself instead of title_id, job's itself instead of job_id and department's name instead of dept_id in the result set, at once.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you forgot `"` in query after `p.dept_id=d.id,`?

Comment: Yes I forgot it. But now it is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `join`:

```
$query = sprintf(
                  "SELECT * 
                   FROM 
                         persons p join titles t on p.title_id=t.id join departments d on  p.dept_id=d.id join jobs j on p.job_id=j.id
                   WHERE 
                         p.person LIKE %s OR 
                         p.phone LIKE %s OR 
                         p.email LIKE %s
                   ", 
                   $search, $search, $search
                  );
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b296f/1)**

Answer (score -1):

Replace SELECT * 
                   FROM  to SELECT distinct * 
                   FROM

Comment: This is not about distinct and also for your sake I have tried it. No solution.